# The use of "that"

Tags: meaning

If you can find somebody and divide up the labor so that you don't feel so overwhelmed by everything that you are doing,  all you have to do sometimes is to ask for help and your life will feel **that** much better.

What is the use of" that"here?
An adverb which emphasizes much ? OR
Pronoun as an object of verb feel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a set phrase, it means your life will feel a lot better. Basically it's not stated how much is "that much" - what it means is, "your life will feel better to the extent that asking for help will make your life better," which doesn't really mean anything but is supposed to be obviously a lot.